# Android - String.format - MissingFormatArgumentException and InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, string, string.format, invocationtargetexception

I have the following code-block -

```
strBody = String.format(getString(R.string.some_string,
                                    strPropertyName,
                                    "some string"
                                                        )
                                              );
```

while R.string.some_string is of this form -

```
some words \'%1$s\' more words. %2$s
```

but i get the following exception on some devices -

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
1   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative   
2   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java, line 515
3   android.view.View$1.onClick View.java, line 3949
... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier: d
1   java.util.Formatter.getArgument Formatter.java, line 1111
2   java.util.Formatter.doFormat    Formatter.java, line 1076
3   java.util.Formatter.format  Formatter.java, line 1042
4   java.util.Formatter.format  Formatter.java, line 1011
5   java.lang.String.format
```

Comment: You are missing format specifier `String.format("%s",your string);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be either

```
 strBody = String.format(getString(R.string.some_string), 
              strPropertyName, item.getString(ObjKombiItem.FIELD_PERMALINK));
```

or

```
 strBody = getString(R.string.some_string, 
                  strPropertyName, item.getString(ObjKombiItem.FIELD_PERMALINK));
```

the first version uses `String.format` to apply the parameter to the String referenced by `R.string.some_string`. The second version does the same thing, but use directly [getString(int resId, Object...objs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)). What you are missing, in your case, is a bracket before the first comma:

```
getString(R.string.some_string,
```

should be

```
getString(R.string.some_string),
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why was it working on testing devices. I was getting properly formatted string. However, android studio was raising a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your string values can be formatted

```
    String result = String.format("%s %s %s", getString(R.string.some_string),
                    strPropertyName, "some string");
```

Comment: I have already specified the format in the string resource. but thanks for the answer